Update data through intermediate table
I have 3 three table like this:

News (number, date, id_title, content, paragraph)
Title (id_title, content)
Detail (id_detail, id_title, paragraph)

The News table



number
date
id_title
content
paragraph




1
2024-01-11
t1




2
2024-02-12





3
2024-03-13
t3




4
2024-04-14






The Title table



id_title
content




t1
c_100


t3
c_300



The Detail table



id_detail
id_title
paragraph




d1
t1
p_101


d2
t1
p_102


d3
t1
p_103


d4
t3
p_301


d5
t3
p_302



I try to update News table with this result:



number
date
id_title
content
paragraph




1
2024-01-11
t1
c_100
p_101






p_102






p_103


2
2024-02-12





3
2024-03-13
t3
c_300
p_301






p_302


4
2024-02-14






But I can only make this:



number
date
id_title
content
paragraph




1
2024-01-11
t1
c_100
p_101


2
2024-02-12





3
2024-03-13
t3
c_300
p_301


4
2024-02-14






query I use:
UPDATE news SET paragraph = detail.paragraph
    FROM news, detail
    WHERE news.id_title = detail.title

when using UPDATE for column paragraph, it just selects the first value. How can I do it right?

You forgot to include that attempt in your question, so we can't see why it's not working as you expect.

You really need to "update" to modern syntax, the ANSI-89 JOIN syntax was superceded way back in 1992. Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs

As for your UPDATE attempt, you are expecting the News table to have seven rows, but it only currently contains 4. You can't use an UPDATE to create new rows, an UPDATE alters the current rows in the table; you need to use an INSERT to create rows. Though storing no value in the majority of columns is a terrible idea. What Number, date, Id_title, and content would be related the paragraph 'p_102' if all those other columns are NULL? You wouldn't know. This smells like an XY Problem. YOu should be normalising your design here.

You should create separate tables that bind the News with Title and Content. Then you will note how easy it is to manage the data. A join between the tables can then display the data in the above format.

Ah yes, I'm working with a VB.NET site, it can output a table like query results table in sql server, so I have to process data properly in sql server, .NET adds data to the table created in the frontend corresponding to the query result table in sql. I'm newbie working with legacy code.

Why do you need to copy data around beteen tables? Such too often leads to data inconsistency.

A good join query will do the trick, no need to update your News table. You also don't need the Content and Paragraph column. (not tested, but the query is something like this)
SELECT A.number, A.date, A.id_title, B.content, C.paragraph 
FROM News A 
LEFT JOIN Title B ON A.id_title = B.id_title 
LEFT JOIN Details C ON A.id_title = C.id_title

the result will not look like what you're expecting the columns and data will all be there. You can just add some logic/code for the presentation part.
